# Bitbucket pipeline not running Chromedriver executable

Tags: selenium, gradle, selenium-chromedriver, bitbucket-pipelines

So I'm running in to an error where I have a simple front end login test to a website using selenium. When I run the test in the bitbucket pipelines I'm running in to this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build\chromedriver.exe
```

Bitbucket yml file

```
image: gradle:6.6.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          caches:
            - gradle
          script:
            - gradle build
          after-script:
            - pipe: atlassian/checkstyle-report:0.2.0
      - step:
          name: Security Scan
          script:
            # Run a security scan for sensitive data.
            # See more security tools at https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&category=security
            - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.4.3
```

Does anyone know what the issue may be ?

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 things:

1. You are specifying the driver file so the route could be incorrect.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build\chromedriver.exe

2. You are using a gradle image

> image: gradle:6.6.0

but I don't think that you have a driver/browser in that image.

You will need to add another image with a browser, like this https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome, you can find more examples here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium and add it to your file. Something like this:

```
image: gradle:6.6.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          caches:
            - gradle
          services:
            - chrome
          script:
            - gradle build
          after-script:
            - pipe: atlassian/checkstyle-report:0.2.0
      - step:
          name: Security Scan
          script:
            # Run a security scan for sensitive data.
            # See more security tools at https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?&category=security
            - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.4.3
definitions:
  services:
    chrome:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome
```

You will need to change your code to use a RemoteWebDriver
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/remote_webdriver_client/